# mysql query to include null values in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table member1 which looks like this. I am editing my table why I want to return all values from pst.

```
id  club_id mobile      pst
1     1     9437054788  6
2     1     9437345602  NULL
3     2     9437056738  35
4     2     9437064876  39
5     1     9437059927  NULL
6     2     9437965276  40
7     1     9437121455  NULL
```

I have a drop-down fields one for club_id and another check-box field for pst with a value of 'select All' on both fields. 'select All' equals '%'.

The solution provided by @TheConstructor works well in this query

```
SELECT group_concat(mobile) FROM `member1` WHERE COALESCE(pst, '') 
LIKE '%' and club_id=1
```

or

```
SELECT group_concat(mobile) FROM `member1` WHERE COALESCE(pst, '') 
LIKE '6' and club_id=1
```

Now I want to have multiple values in the query in place of '6' for example

```
SELECT group_concat(mobile) FROM `member1` WHERE COALESCE(pst, '') 
in (6,35,39,40) or in ('%') and club_id=1
```

How I can achieve that, as at the moment I can return the result with just one value i.e. 6 or 35 or 39 or 40

Comment: Why do you want `NULL` to match one of those four values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you will have noticed `NULL LIKE '%'` will not evaluate to `TRUE` and rows where `pst` is `NULL` are excluded from the result. Now there a different approaches to include rows where `pst` is `NULL`; here are three of them:

1. If you want to get all rows you can just leave out the `WHERE` all together.

   ```
   SELECT group_concat(mobile) FROM `member1`;
   ```
2. If you want to always include `NULL` you can add `OR pst IS NULL`. (Can use index on column `pst`)

   ```
   SELECT group_concat(mobile) FROM `member1` WHERE pst LIKE '%' OR pst IS NULL;
   ```

   If you plan on changing `LIKE '%'` for another predicate, this is probably the fastest SQL on bigger tables.
3. If you want to treat `NULL` as if it was an empty string you can use: (will not use index on column `pst`)

   ```
   SELECT group_concat(mobile) FROM `member1` WHERE COALESCE(pst, '') LIKE '%'
   ```

   [`COALESCE(pst, '')`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) will give the value inside column `pst` if it is not `NULL` or `''` if pst is `NULL`.

   While I regard this to be the most flexible one as you only need to change `'%'` to something different to start filtering and exclude `NULL`-values, MySQL's optimizer will sadly handle this differently from the second query which will cost you performance on big tables where `pst` has an index.

As a last caveat note that [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) will by default only return 1024 characters. This can be changed by setting [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) to a higher value.

Comment: `WHERE COALESCE(pst, '') LIKE '%'`.. invalidates any index on `pst` and will always return true.

Comment: @TheConstructor - is it possible to modify ur suggestion  to replace the like example in ('%') or in (6,35,39,40)

Comment: `IN ('%')` will only select the exact value `'%'`. You can of course use both `IN`-predicates instead of `LIKE '%'`. With 2. you will still get rows where `pst` is `NULL` with 3. you will no longer get them if your `IN` does not contain `''`.

Comment: @TheConstructor Actually ur suggestion at pt.3 is working as expected. only I wanted additional result but when I am trying to use the query - SELECT group_concat(m.mobile)from member m where COALESCE(m.pst, '') in ('%') it is returning null, but with like it is working all-right

Comment: @Pawan that is because `IN ('%')` will search for literal `'%'` (and you only have '6',...) while `LIKE '%'` will search for any value. Or else put: [only with `LIKE` `%`and `_` have a special meaning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) otherwise they stand for themselves.

Comment: In fact you've managed to suggest three separate solutions that are all exactly the same logic and will all return all rows. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @Arth as they stand all three SQLs are returning the same result, but depending on where you want to go from there you will want to use a different one.

Comment: That's fine.. I should have said, please make this clear in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I've wildly misunderstood your question, but I think you want just:

```
SELECT group_concat(mobile) FROM member1
```

The `%` in `WHERE pst LIKE '%'` is a wildcard for zero or more of any character, thus the query will return any `NOT NULL` pst records.. you are way better off using `WHERE pst IS NOT NULL` if you need that logic.

If you need to check the actual character `%` you'll need to escape it; `WHERE pst LIKE '\%'`.. but this is the same logic as `WHERE pst = '%'` as you are checking for equality.

I'm still struggling to understand you but if you are checking for existence in the database of a mobile number the simplest query is:

```
SELECT 1 FROM member1 WHERE mobile = ?
```

Where `?`, is your pass in variable and any rows returned means the record exists. Make sure you use a binding method that is safe from SQL injection.

I would also shy away from using `GROUP_CONCAT` in every case except the one when I am displaying the data as CSV. If you are building a drop-down from the results.. just pull in the separate rows in an array and run through it as you build the HTML.

Comment: As I said I need this value to be compared against the parameter passed from drop-down values of a form. How I can achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using that value as-is, right from the form data.
Are you sure this won't result in security issues?

I would grab the value from $_POST, test it, create a variable with the correct WHERE part of the query dependent on the test and use that in the query string.